# How to make sure the user sees the actual image they uploaded instead of the cached?

Tags: php, html, laravel

When someone uploads an image to the server it is stored like this:

```
$file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->owner_id . '/' .$group_id . '/', "avatar.jpg");
```

This works as intended, however, whenever I upload a new image, the site won't show the new image, but the old one even though it does not exist in the server anymore.

How can I make sure that the image is loaded every time it is changed despite of the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<img src="pathtoimage/avatar.jpg?v=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timestamp behind the url to the image. The browser will see this as a new url and download the image again.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg?0123456789
```

To make sure the timestamp is unique, you can do something like this in php code:

```
echo "http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg?" . time();
```